# Office 365 Delve: Customisation & editing

Tags: office-365

I'm wondering what capability, if any, exists around

1. Customising Delve Pages in Office365 Pages.  I've no specific wishes in mind but am looking for an illustration of any possibilities
2. Customising which properties are shown in Delve.

Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer two both questions would be that there are no options for customising Delve at this point in time.

That's not to say there won't be options in the future, but in general we are seeing a move away from the idea of being able to customise what is there and more towards a world where you can use the apis to build amazing applications in whatever way you want to. :-)

Comment: Exactly what I suspected.  Appreciate the response.